# Can we nuke a Beta and start again?

Tags: discussion, moderation, beta-phase, beta-sites

### Disclaimer

The following case-study is just my opinion and not something the Beta site in question has decided upon. I want to know whether such course of action is in theory possible before presenting it to the Beta site for discussion.
I will use Health.SE *as an example*, but this applies to any Beta site.

---

Health.SE has a few problems (outlined in its respective Meta)

1. A large amount of experienced users have been lost
2. New users ask questions that are off-topic (25% of the new posts in a month don't belong there)
3. We have two interest groups, it's like Mathematics and MathematicsEducators combined
4. ... (this list goes on, but what exactly is wrong is irrelevant here)

Is it **in theory**

- possible to **nuke the site** because it's failing and has no active users
- and **start again from scratch** (i.e. have a new Area51 proposal, this time using the gained knowledge to improve the site and fix previous problems)

As far as I'm aware, this hasn't happened before, so we would be setting a precedent.

What are the requirements before a site could get nuked?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It happened with Literature. That said, if the current Health site is failing, why do you think a new one will succeed?

Comment: I agree Health.SE is a failure, been watching it from time to time. The core problem is that it's REALLY hard to post good answers there, with credible sources.

Comment: This has happened with various topics. Anyone remember the multiple iterations of sex.se?

Comment: How about making a meta post on Health.meta proposing big changes needed and finally implementing them. (In other words, I think you can use meta to draw attention of whole the community and discuss any issue). Hope the site can sustain from failure.

Comment: @Pandya That's what we've done. Including me, 2 users and one mod participated. This is the result after 3 weeks... Health has so many issues that it is easier to hit "reset" than fix everything (scope - what do we do if suddenly 60% of old answers are off-topic etc.)

Comment: @Narusan oh! then a fresh start would be fine.

Comment: @Rory sex.SE is a totally different story. It was never alive for more than a month, as far as I remember. And Health.SE is alive for years.

Comment: It was rather a throwaway comment :-)

Comment: @yannis This is something that would have to be discussed at Health Meta before voting for a restart. I'm certain we will be able to tackle a substantial amount of the core problems by starting differently, though...